# Regex - find all kinds of numbers in a String before a specific Character

Tags: regex, web-scraping

I want to extract a number bevore a list of specific Characters. I want to extract Volume, Pirce and more from different Websites.

For example I want to excract the Volume from here:

```
<td class="data">Single Malt Scotch Whisky der Marke Speyburn 10 Years 40% 0,7l Flasche</td>
or
<td class="data">Irish Whiskey der Marke Bushmills  the Original 40% 1,0l Flasche</td>
```

I tried the following code:

```
re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*?(?=l|L|Liter| Liter| l| L|ml)", string)
```

And this is the result:

```
First String = ['7'] and Second String = ['0']
```

How I get the complete number (0,7 and 1,0)?

For the Volume I tryed to convert the comma into a dot. This works fine for the volume but not for the price.

```
                    if ',' in string:
                        string= string.replace(',', '.')
```

If it is possibible, I want to use the regex also for the price. The difficulty here are the different types of numbers.
Following types are available:

- 10.00€
- 10,00€
- 1,234.56€
- 1.234,56€

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
[-+]?\.?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?= ?[mM]?[lL])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIhctZ/1). To match the measurement units as whole words, add `\b` word boundary at the end of the lookahead pattern, `(?= ?(?:[mM]?[lL]|[Ll]iter)\b)`.

**Details**

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of a dot or comma and then 1+ digits
- `(?= ?[mM]?[lL])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `\?` - an optional space (you may use `\s?` here to match any whitespace)
  - `[mM]?` - an optional `m` or `M`
  - `[lL]` - `l` or `L`.

Note that you do not need `Liter` alterantive in the lookahead if you use `(?= ?[mM]?[lL])`, but if you use a word boundary, you will need to use a `Liter` alternative.